# Odd behavior with RPAD

Tags: oracle, special-characters

I've come across some odd behavior related to RPAD ... figured I'm missing something obvious, hoping somebody can help me out.

I'm just trying to format some simple output  ... and reduced the test case to very simple case:

```
  set serverout on
  declare
     lc_wid  CONSTANT  number := 10;
     lc_sep  CONSTANT  varchar2(10) := ' : ';
     
     lc_NOCOLOR  CONSTANT varchar2(100) := chr(27)||'[0m';
     lc_RED      CONSTANT varchar2(100) := chr(27)||'[32m'||chr(27)||'[1;31m';
     lc_GREEN    CONSTANT varchar2(100) := chr(27)||'[32m'||chr(27)||'[1;32m';
     lc_YELLOW   CONSTANT varchar2(100) := chr(27)||'[32m'||chr(27)||'[1;33m';
  begin
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep || lc_GREEN || 'test'                       || lc_NOCOLOR || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep             || 'test'                                     || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep || lc_GREEN || rpad('test'     ,lc_wid,' ') || lc_NOCOLOR || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep             || rpad('test'     ,lc_wid,' ')               || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep || lc_GREEN || rpad('testing'  ,lc_wid,' ') || lc_NOCOLOR || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep             || rpad('testing'  ,lc_wid,' ')               || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep || lc_GREEN || rpad('something',lc_wid,' ') || lc_NOCOLOR || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep             || rpad('something',lc_wid,' ')               || lc_sep );
  end;
  /
```

(Yep, I'm mucking with colors! fun ... )

That spits out the following:

[image]

as you can see, the short text with no RPAD aligns fine ... and the longer text with rpad aligns fine, however, the "test" and "testing" text are doing something "different" ... O.o

now if I change rpad to pad with "." . it works fine .

```
  set serverout on
  declare
     lc_wid  CONSTANT  number := 10;
     lc_sep  CONSTANT  varchar2(10) := ' : ';
     
     lc_NOCOLOR  CONSTANT varchar2(100) := chr(27)||'[0m';
     lc_RED      CONSTANT varchar2(100) := chr(27)||'[32m'||chr(27)||'[1;31m';
     lc_GREEN    CONSTANT varchar2(100) := chr(27)||'[32m'||chr(27)||'[1;32m';
     lc_YELLOW   CONSTANT varchar2(100) := chr(27)||'[32m'||chr(27)||'[1;33m';
  begin
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep || lc_GREEN || 'test'                       || lc_NOCOLOR || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep             || 'test'                                     || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep || lc_GREEN || rpad('test'     ,lc_wid,'.') || lc_NOCOLOR || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep             || rpad('test'     ,lc_wid,'.')               || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep || lc_GREEN || rpad('testing'  ,lc_wid,'.') || lc_NOCOLOR || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep             || rpad('testing'  ,lc_wid,'.')               || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep || lc_GREEN || rpad('something',lc_wid,'.') || lc_NOCOLOR || lc_sep );
     dbms_output.put_line ( lc_sep             || rpad('something',lc_wid,'.')               || lc_sep );
  end;
  /
```

[image]

so ... it seems short text doesn't work properly with those color codes AND RPAD ... but I'm wondering why ?
Trying to understand what's going on here.

[edit]
sorry, for what it's worth, I'm running in Oracle 12.1.0.2.0
[/edit]

Comment: This might be more about the SQLcl version than the Oracle version. It behaves properly for me in 20.4. (Though needed to `set serveroutput on format wrapped` to get the leading space on the first line; otherwise formatting options, or tab on/off (which was my first guess), don't seem to make a difference.)

Comment: hmm, that thought had crossed my mind ..  my sqlplus client is running on linux, v11.2.0.1.0
I tried the "format wrapped", didn't do anything on this end